# Button fires on double not single click

Tags: xcode

I got view animations to work perfectly in Xcode (slide off the screen on a button click with CGRect.) Unfortunately I have to click the button twice to execute the animation. What have I done wrong? I appreciate any feedback

Here's my .H code

```
@interface AnimationBlocksViewController : UIViewController{
    IBOutlet UIView *theview;
    IBOutlet UIView *theview2;

    BOOL isAnimated;
    BOOL switchback;
}

-(IBAction)animate:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)change:(id)sender;
```

Here's my .M code

```
-(IBAction)animate:(id)sender;{
    if (isAnimated) {

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        [theview setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
        [theview2 setFrame:CGRectMake(320, 0, 320, 460)];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        isAnimated=NO;

    }


    else{

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        [theview setFrame:CGRectMake(-320, 0, 320, 460)];
        [theview2 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        isAnimated=YES;

    }
}

-(IBAction)change:(id)sender;{
    if (switchback) {

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        [theview2 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        switchback=NO;

    }


    else{

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        [theview2 setFrame:CGRectMake(320, 0, 320, 460)];
        [theview setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        switchback=YES;

    }
}
```

It works but I have to double click to trigger the animation, what have I done wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your initial double click, does a subsequent *single* click trigger the animation properly? If so, it may be that you haven't explicitly initialised your `BOOL` variables, though they should default to `NO`. Try doing that and see if it helps.

If you always need to do two taps to animate, maybe try inserting a call to the run loop to see if it's only processing the animation after running on your application thread for a while i.e. it could be that only when it comes to process a second click event does it actually go and fetch any pending animations and execute them. The code for that would be (after you set `isAnimated` and call `commitAnimations`):

```
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] runMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes beforeDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Not sure whether you can just use `nil` for a date but try that too if you like.

Comment: Hmm let me change those animation states and see what happens. The button currently only animates the views on a double click

Comment: YES! It worked! Changing the animation states of my buttons fixed the problem, thank you darvidsOn

Comment: (I changed all the animated states to NO